# How to display responses to the chatbot simultaneously in the html form in the front end?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am building a web application to fill a form. In the front end, I have the html form and chatbot as separate entities. Chatbot is actually a dialogflow application hosted in the cloud. I have trained the chatbot in the cloud. I have four entrie in the form namely name, age , gender and state/country. I want that when i tell the bot about my name, age, gender or state, it shoud be able to simultaneously fill these entries in the html form simultaneously without any lag.

Can anyone help me with this?

I have been trying to do something with dialogflow webhook but could not find a way.

Comment: Well, what have you tried in your webhook that didn't work? Showing the code you used can help us help you. Is this actually an Action? Or is this a chatbot that the user accesses via the website as well?

Comment: I have not tried much with webhok. I was hoping that there will be some functionality in dialogflow webhook which can help in achieving the target. The user can access the bot and the form on the same page or on the same website.

Comment: You say you have the bot in the page. How did you integrate it into the page?

Comment: You haven't really provided much information about your environment or how you've tried to do it, and without that, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: I just copied the html code generated by the dialogflow integration section ( Using <iframe> element). This displayed the chatbot in the page. But the chatbot is running in the cloud and is different entity from rest of the backend.